# Swift GeoPoint get ALL users location ios

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to make a app where everyone can see everyones location at the same map. I can't find any tutorials on how to retrieve ALL users location on the same map.

I have manage to make a script which uploads the users location into Parse with this script:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {


            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, Error : NSError?) -> Void in
   if let geoPoint = geoPoint{

        PFUser.currentUser()? ["location"] = geoPoint
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
```

I have also manage to get the location of the current user.

Any one know how i can display everyones location, not just mine?

Thank you for your time and help. I am very new to Swift so let me know if i need to provide more information.

Here is my display code.

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {


            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, Error : NSError?) -> Void in
   if let geoPoint = geoPoint{

        PFUser.currentUser()? ["location"] = geoPoint
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
self.MapView?.showsUserLocation = true
      self.MapView?.delegate = self
        MapViewLocationManager.delegate = self
        MapViewLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
     self.MapView?.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: false)




  self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }





        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocationManager]){
        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
```

Outside ViewWDidLoad

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.MapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()



    }
```

Comment: Who is "everyone"? Other users of your app?

Comment: Well then isn't it just a matter of how to fetch all your users from Parse API? Isn't it somewhere in their documentation? I'm trying to understand the actual nature of your problem. For now the question seems to be awfully broad and vague for SO. :)

Comment: Okei i am sorry. I want to that when for example you login. You can see my location. Since now i manage to send the logged in users location to parse. Is it a way that i view all locations on the map? If you got the "find my friends" app by apple, that is kindoff what i am trying to make.

Comment: You can se your own location, and all the locations of those who are logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll get help. But this is indeed a lot of work and not trivial to achieve what you want. I'm afraid a simple SO question won't suffice. :)

Comment: Wierd, since it is possible to retrieve all users coordinates from parse. And it is possible to set points at the map and set other locations. Logically it should be possible :)

Answer (score 0):

To get all users location is not so simple as you think. The most time regular app is working in the background. In the background app can be in background or suspended or terminated state ( [about states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)). And you have to get location from any of these states.
 How is it possible: you should enable Background Mode for location tracking for your app. To do it simpler - use significant location tracking for all users, but accuracy will be about 500m.
 To get more accuracy (but **more** difficult implementation) you can send silent push notification to users ([about  silent push](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)), it wakes up app from terminated or suspended states to background state, and now you can get and send users current location to your server.